# Google Play Services Location API simple code not working

Tags: android

I am trying to get user's current location but my app crashes, I just don't understand how to make it work:

This is the Google Play Services Location API, and I followed the instructions as shown here: [Location and context overview](https://developer.android.com/training/location/), yet my code won't work

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            startLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest);

            mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    String latitudeString = location.toString();
                    tv.setText(latitudeString);
                }
            };
        };

    }

    private void startLocationUpdates(LocationRequest mLocationRequest) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText("Not Permitted");
        } else {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
        }
    }

}
```

Crash message is:

> ttempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback, android.os.Looper)' on a null object reference

Comment: code you please crash message

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize FusedLocationClient, 
make this `mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);` in yours onCreate before you call this `startLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: Now I get `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locationer/com.example.locationer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Listener must not be null`. I believe it has something to do with this "looper" which I have no idea what it does, or not? Could you please copy the code to your environment and see maybe it's a problem with my computer?

Comment: Thanks, what may then cause this problem?

Comment: Is your 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)' before init of fused?

Comment: Post your xml file

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize `mFusedLocationClient`

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

}
```

Comment: After adding this line, I get a different error : `Now I get Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locationer/com.example.locationer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Listener must not be null`

Comment: @Fireio post your full stack

Answer (score 0):

**first** 
you should add premission into you manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Second** 
 declear FusedLoction Client and request runtime premission for location get Last Known Location

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);



// request premission here and check out its result and it will work fine 
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                }
            }
    });
}
```

also take a quick look at this [class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java) on github